# Troubles in R with Dates

Tags: r, date

I'm just starting with R. I have the following problem:
I am using the "sesonal" package (http://cran.at.r-project.org/web/packages/season/season.pdf). I wanted to usethe cosinor function but I have a problem I can't solve.

If I use this call:

```
 test = cosinor(data=train_data2, date=as.Date("2013-01-01"))
```

I get:

```
Fehler in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

but the date seams to be in the right format since

```
as.Date("2013-01-01")
```

works fine.

can anyone help me ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: According to the documentation, `date` is a character string that identifies the column in `data` which contains the dates. Look at the examples.

Comment: Looking at that pdf you send, it looks like you aren't using the function correctly. The `date` argument takes a variable, not an actual date.

Comment: Read the documentation: "date: a date variable if type=“daily”, or an integer between 1 and 53 if type=“weekly”, or an integer between 1 and 12 if type=“monthly”."